# Use of "percentage"

Tags: word-usage, percentages

Can I use *percentage* in the following way?

> The percentage of Google users in Internet users is...

Is this a clear usage of the word?

Comment: There is a problem that I for one cannot tell what you mean by "percentage of google users in Internet users".  Is that the percentage of Google users who are Internet users, or the percentage of Internet users who use Google?

Comment: @HotLicks Thank you for your comment. That's what I was worrying about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrasing isn't quite right.  As only some Internet users will use Google you would need to say:

> "percentage of Internet users who use Google"

However, although "percentage" is in common use, it is not alway correctly interpreted by the general public.  If you are writing for the general public it may be more appropriate to write:

> "XX out of 100 Internet users will use Google"

or

> "XX Google users for every 100 Internet users"

Answer (score 0):

*Percentage* is a ratio as a fraction from 100 (hence per-cent).

So if "internet users" equals 100, "google users" would be a certain percentage of "internet users".

So yes, you can use that.

However sometimes using *ratio* instead of *percentage* is easier on the eye, and *ratio* isn't based on a specific number like 100.

Comment: I don't know if "bound by a specific number" is really the right or best way to say that.

Comment: Probably not the best way to say that, but you can represent ratios as fractions of all kinds of numbers. How would you call that property?

Comment: Most likely _based on_ vs. bound.

Comment: I intended to convey a certain negativity to that property, but I suppose a more neutral phrasing is more fitting.